# help with email commands

Tags: command-line, email, mail, mutt, ssmtp

I want to send emails from my Ubuntu PC to other PCs on internet. I also have an account on yahoo.gr,there are some commands like ssmtp or mail or mutt but they don't work for me.
Perhaps I should change the files on the folder: /var/mail ?

Comment: no, the_Seppi, these instructions doesn't help on the post that you suggest...

Answer (score 0):

- **Install [ssmtp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ssmtp) [image: Install ssmtp]**:

  sudo apt-get install ssmtp
- **Edit the ssmtp config file :**

  gksu gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
- **Add these lines in the file and don't forget to edit according to your needs**

  ```
  root=username@gmail.com
  mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
  rewriteDomain=gmail.com
  AuthUser=username
  AuthPass=password
  FromLineOverride=YES
  UseTLS=YES
  ```
- **Enter the email address of the person who will receive your email:**

  ```
  ssmtp recepient_name@gmail.com
  ```
- **Now enter this:**

  ```
  To: recipient_name@gmail.com
  From: username@gmail.com
  Subject: Sent from a terminal!
  ```

  ADD you contents here now
- **To send the email**:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[This links](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/) shows you another 4 different methods how to send mail from terminal

Comment: thank you, but I have a yahoo account. is it a problem  for these lines:   root=username@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
rewriteDomain=gmail.com     ???

Comment: no just replace gmail with yahoo and it will work...

Comment: @teobass you are welcome. hope to help

Comment: Does it say something specific? If not, I assume you're to enter the message.